# RubyOnRails - How to Change the Order in which ActiveRecords are Paginated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I'm building a note-taking app. We have a "note" feature that displays a user's notes in the order they were created. (latest towards the bottom). There's a button that allows the user to duplicate the note; after duplicating, the note is added to the bottom. How do I have the note added directly beneath?

For example:

Before:
note 1
note 2    <-- User clicks "duplicate" button here 
note 3

Actual Result:
note 1
note 2
note 3
note 2 (copy)

Desired Result:
note 1
note 2
note 2 (copy)
note 3

Some of the ideas I had were to add a db column that specifies the order in which the items would be displayed, and then paginating based on that column. Is there a more straightforward way of solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: do you have the same note id for duplicate and original note ?

Comment: no, they'll have different primary keys.

Comment: how are you identifying its a duplicate note?

Comment: I'm not. :) The purpose of duplicating the note was just to copy over the contents. There is nothing linking the new note with the old. The contents of the new note will have appended "(Copy)", and that's pretty much it.

Comment: IMHO i don't think that you can place duplicate note next to the original note if there is no way to find that new note is a duplicate note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways I can think of:

1. Create a column called "order" as you mentioned, so you can programmatically set the order.
2. When you create the copy, hack the **created_at** to copy that the same as the previous one you copied.  You are sorting by **created_at** already so it will end up next to it.

I recommend option 1 as you will make it so the created_at is not trustworthy if you choose option 2.